# Enabling the customer to distribute the iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios

So I have developed an app for a customer and am wondering if they need to have their own developer account to sell the app on the store? …or can they upload to the app store using my developer credentials while retaining the rights and collecting revenue etc?

Surely you can develop something for someone else and then not have to get them to sign up for a developer account to get their app in the store?

Drew

Answer (score 0):

you have to give your distribution provisional profile to client with your developer credentials.

Comment: is the apps developer name will be client's name?? or mine??

Comment: I would like to have me listed as the developer but it's their app.

Comment: then they have to create apple account

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing about Apple Developer account sharing....

If you upload the app with your developer account's distribution profile then developer name of the will be yours as well as the rights and revenue of apps will be yours..

If you upload the app with your clients developer account's distribution profile then developer name of the will be client's as well as the rights and revenue of apps will be client's..

Comment: My client is not a developer though.  Nor do they want to pay or sign up to be one?  They do however have an iTunes connect account for distributing their podcast and comedy albums.

Comment: if they want to receive the revenue by selling the app or in-app purchase then they must have a developer account...